# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration when trying to CHANGE the value of keys(multiple) in a list of dicts depending on other keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

**BackGround**

I have a list of dicts which is the output of a PostGreSql query. This query will output places which are within a specified distance from a given place and details about them. Also built in is a key which tells the code whether a check box on a HTML page has been checked.

this is a shortened version of what is outputted;

dictresult=[{'name_': 'The Three Lions','latelogo': None, 'latenight': 1, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0}, {'name_': 'The Borough Hall', 'latelogo': None, 'latenight': 0, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0},{'name_': 'The Leathern Bottle', 'latelogo': None,  'latenight': 0, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0},{'name_': 'The Cricketers', 'latelogo': None, 'latenight': 1, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0}, {'name_': 'The Sun Inn', 'latelogo': None, 'latenight': 0, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0},{'The Charterhouse Arms', 'latelogo': None, 'latenight': 1, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0}]

this code is then run against it;

```
    for item in dictresult:
    for key, value in item.items():

        if item['latenight_checked'] == 1:
            if item['latenight'] == 
                item['latenight'] ="this is open until " + str(item[dayclose])
                item['latelogo'] = " *L* "
        else:
            item['latenight'] = ""
            item['latelogo'] = ""

        if item['food_avail_checked'] == 1:
            if item['food_avail'] == 1:

                item['food_avail'] = "this is open until " +(str(item[restclose]))
                item['foodlogo'] = " *F* "
        else:
            item['food_avail'] = ""
            item['foodlogo'] = ""
```

**Problem**
This is where I get the error 'RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration' I realise it must be something to do with me changing the values of latenight and latelogo. If I remove the second section (everything associated with food_avail), everything works fine and the changes are made to the keys as necessary:

[{'name_': 'The Three Lions', 'latelogo': ' *L* ', 'latenight': 'this is open until 01:00:00', 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0, },{'name_': 'The Leathern Bottle', 'latelogo': None, 'latenight': 0, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0, },{'name_': 'The Cricketers', 'latelogo': ' *L* ', 'latenight': 'this is open until 01:00:00', 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0},{'name_': 'The Sun Inn', 'latelogo': None, 'latenight': 0, 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0},{'name_': 'The Charterhouse Arms', 'latelogo': ' *L* ', 'latenight': 'this is open until 04:00:00', 'latenight_checked': 1, 'food_avail': 1, 'food_avail_checked': 0}]

I am guessing this is something to do with the way I have implemented the code; I have tried other ways;

```
for item in dictresult:
    for key, value in item.items():


        if item['latenight_checked'] == 1:
            if item['latenight'] == 1:
                item['latenight'] ="this is open until " + str(item[dayclose])
                item['latelogo'] = " *L* "
        else:
            item['latenight'] = ""
            item['latelogo'] = ""

for item in dictresult:
    for key, value in item.items():
#
        if item['food_avail_checked'] == 1:
            if item['food_avail'] == 1:

                item['food_avail'] = "this is open until " +(str(item[restclose]))
                item['foodlogo'] = " *F* "
        else:
            item['food_avail'] = ""
            item['foodlogo'] = ""
```

And also created a temp dict using dictresult.copy() and read from the dictresult and wrote/changed the temp dict.

All of these failed with the same error.

**what I am trying to do **

Basically I want to scan each dict and check certain keys and values then change said value depending on what is there, so that when the list of dicts comes out of the other end of the code, it will still be in one piece to pass through render to an HTML page and I can use the keys to display info wanted.
I was hoping I could iterate the dict and fire all the 'if' statements against each iteration, I am new to python, so I am sure I done something silly, any advice would be gratefully received.

**Edit** Sorry I am using Python 3.82

**Edit 2** I also tried the following with the same result. Latenight works on it's own when I add the food_avail block I get the same error;

```
    for item in dictresult:
    for key, value in item.items():


        if item['latenight_checked'] == 1:
            if item['latenight'] == 1:
                latetemp = str(item[dayclose])
                item.update(latenight = "this is open until " + str(item[dayclose]))
                item.update(latelogo= " *L* ")
        else:
            item.update(latenight = "")
            item.update(latelogo = "")

# tempdict = dictresult.copy()
#
for item in dictresult:
    for key, value in item.items():

        if item['food_avail_checked'] == 1:
            if item['food_avail'] == 1:

                item.update(food_avail = "this is open until " +(str(item[restclose])))
                item.update(foodlogo = " *F* ")
        else:
            item.update(food_avail = "")
            item.update(foodlogo = "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to solve your problem:

```
for k, v in item.copy().items():
```

But then you change your original dict, not the copy.
*update* after realizing your data structure, you do not want to iterate over the dict.

```
for item in dictresult: 
    if item['food_avail_checked'] == 1:
        if item['food_avail'] == 1:
            item.update({"food_avail" : "this is open until " +(str(item[restclose]))})
            item.update({"foodlogo":" *F* "})
        else:
            item.update({"food_avail":""})
            item.update({"foodlogo":""})
```

Comment: I have tried that though I think I have it wrong, could you just check I am doing this right? To read from the copy I have created would be the usual item[' '], to write to the original list of dicts (in this case dictresult) would be dictresult.item[' ']= "". One thing I am not sure about  is how or if I need to iterate through both dicts together.

Comment: sorry I misread your data.  You want the copy on the dict itself.